# Products not updating with load product model by id in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, import-products

> When I load product by below code then product name not updating. what  problem in my code?

`foreach ($catval as $p) {
    $model = $p->MODEL;
    $NAME = $p->NAME;
    $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $productId = $product->getIdBySku($model);
    if (false !== $productId) {
      $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
      $product->setName($NAME);
      $product->save();
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

try use code

```
foreach ($catval as $p) {
    $model          = $p->MODEL;
    $NAME           = $p->NAME;
    $productModel   = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $productId      = (int)$productModel->getIdBySku($model);

    if ($productId) {
      $product = $productModel->load($productId);
      $product->setName($NAME);
      $product->save();
    }
}
```